# Using conditionals inside doctrine query builder?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

My form has a radio field with 3 choices.

```
->add('cash', 'choice', array(
    'choices' => [1 => 'All', 2 => 'With Cash',  3=> 'Credit'],
    'expanded' => true,
    'multiple' => false,
    'mapped' => false,
    'data' => 1,
    'label' => 'operation.labels.cash',
    'attr'=> array("class" => "credit"),
))
```

I want to list all kind of operations (when user send 1), only cash sales(user sends 2),only credit sales(user sends 3).

This is my repository function

```
if ($cash === 1) {
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('sale')
        ->where('sale.createdAt BETWEEN :initDate and :endDate')
        ->setParameter('initDate', $form->get('initDate')->getData())
        ->setParameter('endDate', $form->get('endDate')->getData())
    ;
 } else if ($cash ===2) {
     $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('sale')
         ->where('sale.createdAt BETWEEN :initDate and :endDate')
         ->andWhere('sale.cash =:cash')
         ->setParameter('initDate', $form->get('initDate')->getData())
         ->setParameter('endDate', $form->get('endDate')->getData())
         ->setParameter('cash', true)
    ;
 } else {
     $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('sale')
         ->where('sale.createdAt BETWEEN :initDate and :endDate')
         ->andWhere('sale.cash =:cash')
         ->setParameter('initDate', $form->get('initDate')->getData())
         ->setParameter('endDate', $form->get('endDate')->getData())
         ->setParameter('cash', false)
     ;
 }


return $qb->getQuery()->execute();
```

I want to know if I could improve this code using conditionals inside doctrine query builder.?

Comment: If nothing else you can have if ($cash === 2) $qb->setParameter('cash'); You dont have to call all methodos at once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can refactor your code that way

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('sale')
    ->where('sale.createdAt BETWEEN :initDate and :endDate')
    ->setParameter('initDate', $form->get('initDate')->getData())
    ->setParameter('endDate', $form->get('endDate')->getData());

if ($cash != 1) {
    $qb->andWhere('sale.cash =:cash')
        ->setParameter('cash', $cash == 2);
}

return $qb->getQuery()->execute();
```

You can't take advantage of nothing more than this as, in Doctrine, but more in general, there's no chance to include/exclude a statement unless you check condition directly.

How works this code? You can notice that your code is repeated every time you "change" the condition. You can group it where common operations are done (so, outside the if statement) and add custom behavior only under certain circumstances.

Comment: There is no need for the ternary as `$cash == 2` would result in a boolean anyways.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I would recommend that you <s>put your method into a custom repository  and</s> not pass in the form into your method, but instead just pass the 2 dates and cash variable. That way you can type check them and also reuse the method. Then you could do it like...

```
// Using the beberlei/assert package although you could easily do it yourself
use Assert/Assertion as Assert;

/**
 * @param \DateTime $initDate
 * @param \DateTime $endDate
 * @param integer $cash
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function findBetweenDates(\DateTime $initDate, \DateTime $endDate, $cash)
{
    // Can expand out to "if (not in 1, 2 or 3) throw exception"
    Assert::choice($cash, array (1, 2, 3));

    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('sale');

    $qb
        ->where($qb->expr()->between('sale.createdAt', ':initDate', ':endDate'))
        ->setParameter('initDate', $initDate)
        ->setParameter('endDate', $endDate)
    ;

    if (1 !== $cash) {
        $qb
            ->andWhere($qb->expr()->eq('sale.cash', ':cash'))
            ->setParameter('cash', 2 === $cash)
        ;
    }

    return $qb
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

The `$qb->expr()` isn't necessary here, although "it is greatly encouraged".

Then you can use this call from anywhere you pass in the repository using...

```
$sales = $this->salesRepository->findBetweenDates($start, $end, $cash);
```

***another thought..***

I would also change the choice values to match constant from a class but that's just preference. So something like...

In a model interface (or just your model)..

```
interface SaleInterface
{       
    const CASH_ALL      = 'all';       // or 1
    const CASH_WITH     = 'with_cash'; // or 2
    const CASH_CREDIT   = 'credit';    // or 3

    //...
}
```

In your form..

```
->add('cash', 'choice', array(
    'choices' => [
        SaleInterface::CASH_ALL    => 'All',
        SaleInterface::CASH_WITH   => 'With Cash',
        SaleInterface::CASH_CREDIT => 'Credit'
    ],
```

Then in your repository call you can do readable checks like..

```
Assert::choice($cash, array (
    SaleInterface::CASH_ALL,
    SaleInterface::CASH_WITH,
    SaleInterface::CASH_CREDIT,
));

//...

if (SaleInterface::CASH_ALL === $cash) {
    $qb
        ->andWhere($qb->expr()->eq('sale.cash', ':cash'))
        ->setParameter('cash', SaleInterface::CASH_WITH === $cash)
    ;
}
```

Comment: Great answer with this "little" question. BTW he said that this is already into repo ;)

Comment: I must have skipped that part and just assumed it was in a controller with the form being passed in.